# Software, script or a tool to automate managing which tests to run

Tags: automation, node.js, unit-tests

I have a batch file that lists all the test files I have and asks me which test I want to perform, like

```
Test. [U]nit, [I]ntegration : i (user input)
Integration. [A]ll, [2][U]serInteraction, [3][R]esultGeneration : u
2 User Interaction.

Running "mocha integration\2userint.js" ...
```

So essentially I have configured a batch "option" for each test file I have, which I can choose to run individually or all together.

But adding and removing tests is a pain. I have to update the batch file everytime a new file is added or changed.

Is there a software, script or a tool, that does this automatically, or makes it easier for me to do so?

I basically need it to be aware of and ask me which file(s) I want to test. A GUI with checkboxes would be ultimate! but I'll take anything.

I'm working in node.js on Windows 8.

Also I have cygwin installed (although not much experience with linux scripting). If a script that could run in cygwin and do the job that would be cool too.

Comment: What OS we're talking about here? For Linux, it would be a simple adjustment of the shell script to automatically 1) list the directories (Unit, Integration) and 2) the files in the selected directory, turning their names into options, and then run the selected one. That would auto-update whenever you add a directory/file. But from the word "Batch" I rather assume you need it for Windows? Any other requirements? Please, [edit] your question and include them :)